# The maximum of a functional

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Under what conditions can we state the following?
$$ \max_{\theta>0} F \left( \theta \right)= \int_{\rho_{min}}^{\rho_{max}} g \left( \rho \right)\pi\left(\rho,\widehat{\theta \left( \rho \right)} \right)d\rho$$
where,
$$ F\left ( \theta \right )=\int_{\rho_{min}}^{\rho_{max}}g\left(\rho \right )\pi\left(\rho,\theta \right)d\rho $$
and
$$\widehat{\theta\left( \rho \right)}=\operatorname{argmax} \pi\left(\rho,\theta \right).$$

Let $\rho_{min}=0$ and $\rho_{max}=1$. We can also assume that $g(\theta)$ and $\pi(\rho,\theta)$ are proper densities of $\rho$ and the parameter $\theta>0$. Also assume that the densities are unimodal.

Alternatively, we can state the problem in the following way: Determine the conditions that satisfy
$$ \max_{\theta>0} F \left( \theta \right)= \int_{0}^{1} g \left( \rho \right)\max_{\theta>0}(\pi\left(\rho,\theta \right))d\rho.$$

Comment: Please check you MathJax syntax.